# How change chromium window size in maximized state

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

How i can limit window size in maximized state chromium? launch from puppeteer

[viewport != window size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa7cu.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chromium launch flag: `--window-size=x,y` where x and y are the values you want.

[Source](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) - a great reference to learn more about the plethora of other launch flags you can use with chromium.

Comment: if i click on maximize button, this not work

Comment: me need limit size maximized mode (--start-maximized)

Comment: Not sure I understand, if you launch with --start-maximized the window will be...maximized. You can either maximize the window or set its size but not both.

Comment: maximized window have W and H, need limit this,  for fake DISPLAY resolution for sites